# Question about meaning of highlighted part

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Q: I usually wear heels because I think they're sexier, but lately I've been going for casual drinks in flats and getting hit on. Is there something to a flat shoe that's enticing, and which ones should I be wearing?
>
> A: It's possible that guys see your flats and think, "Hey, she seems chill and low maintenance." Or that they are less intimidated than they might be if you had the added height a pair of heels would normally give you. It's also possible that they never noticed your shoes in the first place and were responding to something you were not even aware of. There's really no way of knowing.
>
> **As sexy as high heels are**, their real value lies in how they make you feel and how you project that feeling out into the world. If you feel cool, laid back, and confident, it doesn't really matter how high your heels are. And although there are not nearly as many fabulous flats in the world as there are fabulous heels, there is usually an appropriate flat equivalent for any high heel.

Does the expression "as sexy as high heels are" , here mean " although high heels are sexy" ? If so, how do we use as to mean although?

Answer (score 1):

A phrase that follows this pattern:

**as {adjective} as {noun} {verb}**

for example:

**As tall as skyscrapers may be...

As expensive as the Mercedes is...

As sexy as high heels are...**

These phrases, when they introduce a sentence, are a kind of concession, which could be paraphrased as follows:

**Though skyscrapers may be tall, Superman can leap them in a single bound.**

**Though the Mercedes may be expensive, there are other cars more expensive.**

**Though high heels may be sexy, their real value lies in how they make you feel.**